# Iif function in SQL Server Report Builder 2012 3.0

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, iif, ssrs-expression

I'm trying to make an automatic invoice but the final part gets me stuck. If a client is not from the same country as the supplier then he shouldn't pay VAT. To get this in my invoice I'm trying to insert an expression but it gives the following error:

> *'The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox16.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[1]’ contains an error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.'*

This is the expresion I use:

```
=IIf(First(Fields!CustomerCountry.Value, "Invoice"))<>(First(Fields!SupplierCountry.Value, "Invoice")),0,((SUM(Fields!DurationHours.Value * Fields!HourlyRate.Value))*0.21)
```

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure if the methodology is helpful but I've noticed that when I have big query like you do, it is better to break them into small chunks and then use the necessary brackets (us) / parentheses (uk)

Comment: To get more audience please tag your report builder questions with `reporting-services` tag

Comment: @AndyK Shouldn't those be reversed? In US parlance, this [ would be a bracket and this ( would be a parenthesis. I think in the UK they are [ square bracket and ( round bracket.

Comment: Hi @TPhe, I looked at this : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168762/brackets-vs-parenthesis

Comment: @AndyK right, that link seems to say that its called a parenthesis in the us and a bracket in the UK. The way you've written your comment it seems like you are suggesting it is a bracket in the us and a parenthesis in the uk, which is opposite of what my understanding is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra parenthesis in your iif statement, at the first `First` function. Try this instead:

```
=IIf(First(Fields!CustomerCountry.Value, "Invoice")<>(First(Fields!SupplierCountry.Value, "Invoice")),0,((SUM(Fields!DurationHours.Value * Fields!HourlyRate.Value))*0.21))
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either. It gives me the following error: *The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox16.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[1]’ contains an error: [BC30198] ')' expected.*

Comment: You are also missing an ending parenthesis. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @JorgenV Can you accept TPhe's answer?  This will helps others who come after you.

Answer (score 1):

Just remember to keep it very simple and then build.

Start with something like the following:
[image: IIF Construct]